# First android app for iOS developer

Tags: java, android, objective-c, ios, android-layout

i am iOS app developer. Now when i created an app on iOS i want to do the same on android. With java i was familiar just now need some time to remember.

i was looking at some tutorial how to do one or other things. But what i can't find is the basics how everything works. How classes is interacting with each other.

For example i want to create registration window with few buttons and alerts. 
I want registration window to be called just once when app is installed and just that.

Should i create new java class and few layouts, one for View with buttons and other for Alerts ?

Or should i create other class for alerts if i need them in other flow of my app ?

And how i should call that window with registration from my main class, which is

```
extends Activity
```

Also if there are some developers who came this road from objective-c (iOS) to java (android). It would be nice for some share experience how they did that.

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very few of the concepts in iOS and Android are similar. On Android you have [Activites](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), [Intendts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) the [Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html). When you design your layout it should be resolution independent. You have a search, back and a menu button and variable hardware. All of this has no equivalent in iOS.

That said, I think you just have to read the basic concepts and the [getting started guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/index.html) no matter if you come from iOS or never have done mobile development before.

**EDIT**
To answer your concrete question. Take a look at the [lifecycle of an Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and [Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). With this, you could do some action on the first start of your main Activity and store some flag in the preferences when it's done. On the next start you just test that preference and skip the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one activity (.java file)  and one layout(.xml file with buttons and input boxes) , alerts could be toast notifications:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Answer (score 0):

All you require for this is a **activity** and a layout **xml** for that activity, this activity will be your main ie the entry point to your application, in that activity **oncreate** method you can check if it is registered or not by setting a flag or something which will direct to the next activity if its registered.

GOOD LUCK...

Answer (score 0):

Just like your nibs in iPhone you create **xml** layouts in Android. And for view controllers here you make **activity**. One important thing is AndroidManifest.xml file, it contains all information of your app (like plist) plus all the activity information(Intent type and launcher methods).